# boost filesystem in cygwin directory iterator

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin

Got stuck with boost while using filesystem in cygwin. The error occurs in this simple part of code:

```
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char **argv)

{
    path targetDir("/cygdrive/d/Repositories/testmodels/");

    if (exists(targetDir)) {
        cout << "directory exists!" << endl;
        directory_iterator end_itr; // default construction yields past-the-end
        for (directory_iterator itr(targetDir); itr != end_itr; ++itr)
        {
            cout << *itr << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The following error occurs during linking:

```
CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4d3): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&)'
CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4d3): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&)'
CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6detail17sp_counted_impl_pINS_10filesystem6detail11dir_itr_impEE7disposeEv[_ZN5boost6detail17sp_counted_impl_pINS_10filesystem6detail11dir_itr_impEE7disposeEv]+0x18): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&)'
CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZN5boost6detail17sp_counted_impl_pINS_10filesystem6detail11dir_itr_impEE7disposeEv[_ZN5boost6detail17sp_counted_impl_pINS_10filesystem6detail11dir_itr_impEE7disposeEv]+0x18): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&)'
collect2: fout: ld gaf exit-status 1 terug
make[2]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/test.dir/build.make:454: test/test.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Directory '/cygdrive/d/Repositories/test/build' exited
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:144: test/CMakeFiles/test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Directory '/cygdrive/d/Repositories/test/build' exited
make: *** [Makefile:98: all] Error 2
```

I assume it's 32/64 bit issue, but I don't know how to solve it...

**PS no. 1**

CMake also warned me for problems ahead (no errors though). Here's the relevant extract:

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.4.0
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/Platform/CYGWIN.cmake:15 (message):
CMake no longer defines WIN32 on Cygwin!
(1) If you are just trying to build this project, ignore this warning or
quiet it by setting CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=0 in your environment or in
the CMake cache.  If later configuration or build errors occur then this
project may have been written under the assumption that Cygwin is WIN32.
In that case, set CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=1 instead.
(2) If you are developing this project, add the line
set(CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32 0) # Remove when CMake >= 2.8.4 is required
at the top of your top-level CMakeLists.txt file or set the minimum
required version of CMake to 2.8.4 or higher.  Then teach your project to
build on Cygwin without WIN32.
```

So I re-run with `cmake -DCMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=0 ..`, the warning message disappears, but the errors still occur.

**PS no. 2**

Commenting out the for-loop in the above code makes the linking errors disappear. No clue how this can happen...

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:** Boost was installed with the Cygwin installer. I tried this both in Cygwin and Cygwin64. The CMakeLists.txt is appended below (the executable is created in a separate CMakeLists file in the src/ subdirectory, which is of no importance here).

CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Project
project(test)

set(CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32 0)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
# Version Number
set(VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set(VERSION_MINOR 0)

# CMAKE version
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# C++11 support
if(WIN32)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
else()
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")
endif(WIN32)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

# Malloc & Unistd
INCLUDE (CheckIncludeFiles)
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES (malloc.h HAVE_MALLOC_H)
add_definitions(-DHAVE_MALLOC_H)
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES (unistd.h HAVE_UNISTD_H)
add_definitions(-DHAVE_UNISTD_H)

# General include, for third party header files.
message(STATUS "Including /include")
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem REQUIRED)

# Subdirectories
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
add_subdirectory(src)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install boost libraries in Cygwin terminal or try to install boost via Cygwin installer (easier).
If it doesn't help, show your CMakeLists file.

Comment: Boost was indeed installed through the Cygwin installer. I updated my post with added CMakeLists.txt

Comment: maybe adding the following lines will help:  

`if (Boost_FOUND)  
   include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})  
   target_link_libraries(test ${Boost_LIBRARIES})  
endif()`